# Rails: acts_as_follower listing blocked users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, acts-as-follower

I'm doing a job with [acts_as_follower](https://github.com/tcocca/acts_as_follower) gem that users can follow others users. The documentation says:

> To get all of the records that an object is following that have not
>   been blocked use the following

```
user.all_following
# Returns an array of every followed object for the user, this can be a collection of different object types, eg: User, Book
```

I did that and I'm stiil getting blocked users on loop.

I tried to put a conditional:

```
<% if current_user.following?(user) %>
```

But this line also show blocked users, because even with user blocked, it stiil followin user in the follow model.

Currently my call is like this:

```
<% current_user.all_following.each do |user| %>
```

Someone knows how I can definitely prevent blocked users from being listed on loop?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you verify the users are indeed blocked?  Do they show up on `current_user.blocks` ?  If that works, you could put a conditional like... `<% current_user.all_following.each do |user| %>`  and in the next line, `<% next if current_user.blocks.include? user %>`

Comment: It works! Thanks!